# How to ignore a table inside another table when I am looking for tr elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script which hides table rows depending on the name in the first column. It works pretty well for single tables.

I add a table inside a row with additional information for the rooms of the location. Now also the rows in the additional table are marked as hidden if the search string not match.

How can I modify the *mySearchFuntion* so that only row from the main table *myTable* are hidden? The script should ignore the other tables.

```js
function mySearchFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="mySearchFunction()" class="form-control" autofocus placeholder="Search by location name...">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
     <th>Location name</th>
     <th>Rooms</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>loction AB</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>room 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>room 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>loction EF</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>room 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>room 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: do you want to loop through inner table rows or you want to ignore them

Comment: Just give the columns you want to filter by a class, then only search on those, instead of all `tr` elements, only those with `.your-class`

Comment: @secretsuperstar the script should ignore the other tables

Comment: @DarrenSweeney can you post your answer with an example? I am not so familiar with javascript. How can I select elements by there class?

Comment: Are you saying you want to hide the row but not the contents of the hidden row?

Comment: @DreamTeK no, if the search string not found in the first column of the "myTable" the full row should be hide. For the other rows the content should be display including the table inside the row. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get only the direct children of the main table, you can use *children* property.

Change the following:

```
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

To

```
table = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");
tr = table.children;
```

```js
function mySearchFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");
  tr = table.children;

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="mySearchFunction()" class="form-control" autofocus placeholder="Search by location name...">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
     <th>Location name</th>
     <th>Rooms</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>loction AB</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>room 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>room 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>loction EF</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>room 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>room 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

**This works?**

**JS**

```
// Hides main rows that do not have a table inside
function mySearchFunction() {
   $('#myTable > tr').has('table').css("display","block")
   $('#myTable > tr').has(':not(table)').css("display","none")
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="mySearchFunction()" class="form-control" autofocus placeholder="Search by location name...">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
     <th>Location name</th>
     <th>Rooms</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>loction AB</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>room 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>room 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>loction EF</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>room 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>room 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i am also open for another solution that works with jQuery. This is not a full working example? can you please expand your answer with the example above?

Comment: With jQuery you can do it in two lines, try to do it to see if you have installed in your project ,  jQuery automatically